# How to attach files to email using Get-ChildItem in Powershell

Tags: powershell, email-attachments

I am trying to write a Powershell script that does the following:

1. Check all files in a directory for a valid string
2. Take every file that contains that valid string and then send them as an email attachment

I do not care if one email is sent with all of the valid files or if an email is sent for each valid file.

The following code is what I have but it errors out when trying to attach the files saying *Send-MailMessage : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name '*

```
$ValidFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Results -Recurse |
                Select-String -Pattern "Test" |
                  Select-Object -Unique Path

foreach ($ValidFile in $ValidFiles)
{

    $From = 'test <test@test.com>'
    $To = 'me <me@test.com>'
    $Subject = "Valid File Found"
    $Username = "Test-Domain\test"
    $Password = ConvertTo-SecureString "notrealpassword" -AsPlainText -Force
    $Creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username, $password)
    $Body = "Please review the attached files"
    $Attachment = $ValidFile | Out-String
    $SMTPServer = "test-com.mail.protection.outlook.com"

    Send-MailMessage -From $From -To $To -Subject $Subject -Credential ($Creds) -Attachments $Attachment -UseSsl -Body $Body -DeliveryNotificationOption OnSuccess, OnFailure -SmtpServer $SMTPServer
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure that `$ValidFiles` contains only *strings* (file paths):

```
$ValidFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Results -Recurse | 
                Select-String -List -Pattern "Test" | 
                  ForEach-Object Path
```

- Adding `-List` to [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) makes the search stop at the *first* match found in a given file, which obviates the need for `Select-Object -Unique`.
- [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) outputs `[pscustomobject]` instances with the specified property/properties, even if only *one* property `Path` is specified; while you could use `-ExpandProperty Path` instead to get just the `.Path` property *value*, it is simpler to use [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) with the property name instead.

Then, use `$ValidFile` - which is now a path *string* -  *directly* as the `-Attachments` argument (which is `[string[]]`-typed, but also accepts a scalar `[string]` instance (single string)).

- Generally, do *not* use [`Out-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-string), unless you want a *formatted for display* representation of the input object(s).

Answer (score 0):

Out-string stops $Attachment from getting populated.

```
$Attachment = $ValidFile | Out-String
```

Try

```
 $Attachment = $ValidFile
```

Comment: This still throws the same error. I originally added the Out-String because it would throw an error along the lines of "Cannot have type Object requires type String[]"